# Adding round corners to Android Layout leaves white edges

Tags: java, android, xml, constraints, shapes

I'm trying to create a `Layout` with rounded corners and I used `shape` to help me do so, but when adding the rounded corners, the background white color also stays.

It might be also important to note that I am using this `layout.xml` as ContentView for `Dialog`:

```
final Dialog MyDialog = new Dialog(this);
MyDialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout.xml);
```

This is my **layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play_song"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:text="Play"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_song"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And drawable **round_corners.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/gray_text"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/colorBlack" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

And this is the result I get:

[image]

How can I remove the white corners?

Comment: take the style param out of the constraint layout and see what appears.

Comment: I forgot to take it away, I was just testing to see if the style would help but nor removing or adding it does anything

Comment: try setting dialog background as transparent in code.. !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the below mentioned line of code. it will set a transparent background to your dialog.

```
MyDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: That works, thank you

Comment: Welcome. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks alot man :)